# Windows like quick launch for Gnome

Tags: gnome

I'm trying to get a Windows like bottom panel. I'm using dash to panel extension, running on Ubuntu 20.04. I've enabled ungrouping, and now it looks like I want to:

[image]

However, I would also want to have a quick launch section. Not like favorites, because favorites icons, once clicked, get replaced with the running app label. Which is pushing all the other favorites to the right. So instead of something like this:

[image]

I would like it to look like this:

[image]

Is there an easy way to achieve it?

Comment: Just to note that KDE is setup this way by default. If you or others haven't tried it `sudo apt install kde-plasma-desktop` (I think) will install.

Comment: Uhm switching to KDE is quite serious I would like to avoid such a big change if possible. Maybe there is an easy solution.

Comment: It would be up to the developers of Dash to Panel to add a quick launch option.  https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1160/dash-to-panel/  Ask them for a feature addition to it.

Comment: @pbhj looks like there is no solution to such a simple issue ;-) farewell gnome. just installed KDE and I like it.